# HTTP Post Request API - Parsing JSON wrapped in Single Quotes

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, encoding, json-serialization

My API accept only Single Quote wrapped JSON. Like:

> '{"api_key":"key_api1234","api_secret":"asdfg","uniqueid":"LDM23564GQQP","password":"test1","pin":"94729"}'

I could find a definitive answer neither here nor on the internet.

I Tried many syntax changes on JSON.

```
let parameters = ["api_key": "key_api1234",
                      "api_secret": "asdfg",
                      "uniqueid": "LDM23564GQQP",
                      "password": "test1",
                      "pin": "94729"]

    guard let url = URL(string: "https://dev-api.authenticateuser") else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else { return }
    request.httpBody = httpBody

    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }

        if let data = data {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(json)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }

        }.resume()
```

I am receiving a 500 Error

Comment: Post code as code, not as image

Comment: What about transforming into JSON, then adding yourself the single quotes?

Comment: BTW That's a terrible API for couple of reasons: 1. Claims it accepts json, but expects a string that is not a valid json 2. Doesn't return a proper error code

Comment: @larme Yes, look at my answer, I tried to make it.

Comment: @mag_zbc I agree.

Comment: Just do `let singleQuote = "'".data(encoding.utf8); request.httpBody = singleQuote + httpBody + singleQuote` (this might not compile, but you should get the idea), but as noted by mag_zbc, that's a bad API.

Comment: Thank you @Larme. I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bad design API.
Forcing to embed the JSON into single quotes, I'd suggest if you cant to tell the back-end developper to fix it.

Still, if you want it to work, you can just convert single quote to `Data`, and what you called `httpBody`, append that single quote before and after.

With bad practice with force unwrap (use of `!`), but to emphasize the logic:

```
let parameters = ["api_key": "key_api1234",
                  "api_secret": "asdfg",
                  "uniqueid": "LDM23564GQQP",
                  "password": "test1",
                  "pin": "94729"]

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "www.stackoverflow.com")!)

let singleQuote = "'".data(using: .utf8)!
let parametersJSON = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])

let finalBody = singleQuote + parametersJSON + singleQuote
print("request.httpBody string: \(String(data: finalBody, encoding: .utf8)!)")
request.httpBody = finalBody
```

Output:

```
$>request.httpBody string: '{"api_key":"key_api1234","uniqueid":"LDM23564GQQP","pin":"94729","password":"test1","api_secret":"asdfg"}'
```

Comment: Totally agree. I will. Help me a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Inserted Single Quotes inside the String and transform it to Data.

Problem solved:

```
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://dev-api.authenticateuser") else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("*/*", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    let jsonData = "'{\"api_secret\":\"asdfg\",\"uniqueid\":\"LDM23564GQQP\",\"pin\":\"94729\",\"password\":\"test1\",\"api_key\":\"key_api1234\"}'".data(using: .utf8)

    request.httpBody = jsonData
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }

        if let data = data {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(json)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }

    }.resume()
```